# asp.net mvc url to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i am creating mvc application and is it possible to get the url to string somehow?
my url is like:http://localhost:7264/Asortiman/Browse?kategorije=327
and in the head of some view i would like to get this url like string and take last 3 digits in this case 327 and use it as param in my function.

Comment: Are you saying you want your URL to look like `http://localhost:7264/Asortiman/Browse/327`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you do it at the Controller level and send it with the ViewBag dynamic object?

I Suppose your Controller is Asortiman and your Action method is Browse. Then if you define your method like;

```
public ActionResult Browse(int kategorije){
ViewBag.KategoriJe = kategorije;
return View();
}
```

Then at the view you can now reach it with the same dynamic object. For further use see the default mvc application project at the vs2010

Comment: Thanks i solved it on much easier way:
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;